# How to scroll to an item using MVVM Prism and ReactiveCommand in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, reactiveui, xamarin-forms-4

Xamarin Forms 4.0 recently released a CollectionView that lets us scroll to a specific item in a collectionView.

I have a collection view with 10 items in it that doesn't fill the screen. ([Microsoft Sample Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo3su.png)). I'm using ReactiveUI and MVVM Prism to handle all my logic within my ViewModel.

So far I'm able to handle navigating based on click using `SelectedItem` and `SelectionChangedCommand`. The next feature I wanted to handle was to scroll to the item I selected. I've searched through the forums and had no luck. The example only shows you how to do it in a code behind not through MVVM Prism / ReactiveUI. Thanks in advance!

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ScrollButtons"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}"
                Grid.Row="2" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                HeightRequest="90"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MenuItemSelectedCommand}"
                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BackgroundColorShell}">
```

Comment: Sorry, you want to manual scroll to SelectedItem or handle when CollectionView scroll to SelectedItem?

Comment: @PhatHuynh Manually scroll to a selected item. I have a menu bar at the bottom of my screen with 10 menu items, I click on the 7th or 8th item, it navigates to that page, I want to be able to scroll to that item I clicked on using Prism / Reactive Commands.

Comment: You need to get the **CollectionView** on your **ViewModel** then use **ScrollTo** method.

Comment: @PhatHuynh How do I connect a CollectionView to a ViewModel? I've only been binding properties. I've always wondered this is probably the best way. I know that you can use x:Name=myCollectionView in Xamarin forms and you can reference that in your code behind. How do you reference the collectionView in a view model.

Comment: You can pass it to **ViewModel** by handle **BindingContextChanged** on **View**.

Comment: Do you have any Microsoft documents or tutorials that shows how to do this? I'm a Xamarin beginner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show you how to pass **CollectionView** to **ViewModel**.
First, define 2 interfaces like

```cs
public interface IHasCollectionViewModel{
  IHasCollectionView View {get;set;}
}
public interface IHasCollectionView{
  CollectionView CollectionView {get;}
}
```

Next, on your **View** implements **IHasCollection**

```cs
public class YourView: ContentPage, IHasCollectionView {
   CollectionView CollectionView => ScrollButtons; // your CollectionView x:Name
   protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
   {
            if (this.BindingContext is IHasCollectionViewModel hasCollectionViewModel)
            {
                hasCollectionViewModel.View = this;
            }
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
   }
}
```

Next, on your **ViewModel** implements **IHasCollectionViewModel**

```cs
public class YourViewModel: IHasCollectionViewModel {
       public IHasCollectionView View { get; set; }
       // use CollectionView like
       private void ScrollToItem(int index){
             View.CollectionView.ScrollTo(index); // don't forget check null
       }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When scrolling an item into view, the exact position of the item after the scroll has completed can be specified with the position argument of the ScrollTo methods. This argument accepts a ScrollToPosition enumeration member.

CollectionView defines properties, which are backed by bindable properties

[Control scroll position - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling#control-scroll-position-when-new-items-are-added)